# Relative consistency of ETCS over the theory of a well-pointed topos with NNO

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, set-theory

EDIT: I'm bumping this, because I'm still curious, and because I have a relative consistency result over the theory of a well-pointed topos with NNO, and I am wondering how much baggage I save by not assuming AC in the base model (I'm not using AC in the proof either).

Gödel's well-known proof of the implication $Con(ZF) \Rightarrow Con(ZFC)$ used the construction of the inner model $L$ in $ZF$ to get a model of $ZFC$ (and in fact much more). However such a construction is not (immediately) available in a category-theoretic approach to set theory. In particular, given a [well-pointed](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-pointed+topos) [topos](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos) with [NNO](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/natural+numbers+object), which is the set theory [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) minus the axiom of choice, I wonder whether there is any way to construct a model of ETCS. On the face of it, it doesn't seem likely, as objects of the given topos are quite amorphous.

The only thing I can think of (admittedly I haven't tried very hard) is by passing to a model of ZF via [pure sets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set), constructing $L$, and then taking the category of sets of $L$. But this is somewhat unsatisfactory, as it leaves the comfy realm of categories and heads out into material set theory. So:

> Is there a category-theoretic construction of a model of ETCS from a well-pointed topos with NNO?

Comment: Can you do a category-theoretic version of HOD? Using HOD instead of L may be more amenable to category-theoretic methods, since it seems to be less intensive with transfinite recursion. Indeed, perhaps one can get at the class OD rather directly with category-theoretic methods, and then you'd need only get into the hereditary core of it to produce HOD.

Comment: Naïvely one might just take the full subcategory of the topos with NNO spanned by the well-orderable objects... but there's no guarantee that this subcategory is closed under power objects, so this probably doesn't work. But maybe a non-full subcategory will do the trick. 

Comment: @Joel, the 'H' of HOD makes no sense in categorical set theory, since sets do not have sets as elements, and also the cumulative hierarchy doesn't exist a priori (it is constructed as part of Fourman's translation to material set theory). @Zhen - non-full sounds reasonable, since the functions in L surely do not exhaust the possible functions between the same sets considered in the ambient model of ZF.

Comment: Oh, I am aware of the difficulties, and you can't expect it to be easy, but surely the power objects already give you at least *some* sense of element-of-element, although that may already be pushing you into your discarded pure sets proposal. The content of my suggestion was meant to be: L is not the only way to prove Con(ZF) implies Con(ZFC), and HOD and OD may be more amenable than L category theoretically.

Comment: Another proposal, which might be similar to Zhen Lin's: another way to construct $L$, rather than by transfinite recursion, is to close the class of ordinals under the ten Goedel operations. Each of these operations is essentially trivial and easily handled category-theoretically. So one wants to build the subcategory essentially by closing the well-orderable objects (i.e. the ordinals) under those operations. 

Comment: You could try adding a generic section to every epimorphism. The site's objects would consist of triples $(p,e,s)$ where $p:A \to B$ is epimorphism, $e:B_0 \to B$ is mono, and $s:B_0\to A$ is such that $ps = e$; and the morphisms $(p,e,s) \to (q,f,t)$ are such that $p$ is a restriction of $q$ and $t$ is an extension of $s$ in the only sensible fashion. (Details are too much for a comment box.) *Caveat*: this is a large site and it's not clear that it will work in only one shot.

Comment: All these are nice (potential) answers, why not use the answer box? :)

Comment: François's idea seems most topos-theoretic in spirit, but I would have to think about it much longer before I could say whether it works or not. (It's also the most conceptually clean, somehow: we want epimorphisms to split, so we just wish them into existence!) 

Comment: François's idea is very interesting, but the analogue of it for ZF does not work, since one cannot always force ZFC over a ZF model. Although one can force to make any given set well-orderable, simply by making it countable, for example, nevertheless one can have a model of ZF in which every uncountable cardinal is singular, and such a model has no forcing extension satisfying ZFC. 

Comment: Joel is right. Moreover, it appears that replacement is necessary to make internal sense of sheaves over a large site like that one.

Comment: The $L$ approach also seems to need replacement. Given a wellordering $\alpha$, we can make sense of "the pure transitive set $X$ is $L_\alpha$," we can show that any two such pure transitive sets must be isomorphic and we even have the condensation lemma. If $L_\alpha$ exists for each wellordering $\alpha$, then we can make sense of "the constructible subcategory" by allowing only sets and morphisms that are materializable in some $L_\alpha$. However, replacement is needed to show that there is an $L_\alpha$ for every wellordering $\alpha$ and then that exponentials materialize.

Comment: I think getting an $L_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ might not be too difficult, especially if we follow Joel and use the Gödel operations instead of definability. The point is that every element of $L_\alpha$ has a name built from standard syntactic stuff plus ordinals $<\alpha$. On the other hand, the power set axiom in $L$ looks like a big problem in the absence of replacement.

Comment: I would like to add to the question: "And if there is a category-theoretic proof of the relative consistency, does this give a new perspective on the relative consistency of ZFC over ZF?"

Comment: @Martin: A proof along the lines suggested in the comments here would not give a new perspective, since it would just be a translation into category theory of an existing set-theoretic proof.  But there might well be a category-theoretic proof along entirely different lines that does give a new perspective.  (The analogous possibility for the consistency of $\neg AC$ was realized by Freyd's topos-theoretic proof, which is genuinely different from previous forcing proofs, though it could, after the fact, be recast as a forcing argument.)

Comment: Andreas and Joel, what exactly do you mean by the syntactic approach? The rud-closure of an ordinal (as I think of it) doesn't contain $V_\omega$ as an element.

Comment: Francois, I was originally thinking in terms of the definability approach to $L$, where each set in $L$ can be named by a comprehension term (involving formal symbols $L_\alpha$). In terms of the Gödel operations, you'd need to include symbolism for all the things used in the construction, not only the Gödel operations themselves but also the "collect all the previous stuff together" at limit ordinals.

Comment: Some ideas about François' first proposal from other category theorists: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.science.mathematics.categories/7558

Comment: I should remark that these are very un-material in their approach!

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that in "On the strength of Mac Lane set theory", Mathias describes a somewhat more structural approach to the constructible universe L, which may be similar to some of what has been mentioned above.  I think that would be a good place to start for anyone who wanted to understand an analogue of L in ETCS.

Comment: Andreas, doesn't "collect all the previous stuff together at limit ordinals" use replacement? Or is there another way to collect the stuff?

Comment: Mike has a good idea. In his recent work on what he calls *provident sets*, Mathias shows that closure under *rudimentary recursion* is enough to get at a meaningful $L$. Unfortunately, rudimentary recursion is a weak form of replacement.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you point out where the following argument falls down? Claim: If $A$ and $B$ are well-orderable then so is $A^B$. Proof: Let $\alpha\simeq A$ and $\beta\simeq B$ be ordinals. Then $\alpha^\beta$ is hereditary-ordinal-definable. Since Choice holds in HOD, $\alpha^\beta$ is well-orderable. Then since $A^B\simeq\alpha^\beta$ we have that $A^B$ is well-orderable.

Comment: @Oscar I would guess that the set of functions in HOD is not the same as the set of functions in the ambient universe. Otherwise take $A=\alpha=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\beta= \omega$. I'm pretty sure there are models of ZF where $P(\omega) \simeq \{0,1\}^\omega$ is not well-orderable.

Answer (score 3):

I confess that I am not altogether clear what the Question requires, whilst many of the Comments are beyond me, but here is a construction of which you may not be aware and which may throw some light on the issues.

It is based on my paper [*Intuitionistic Sets and Ordinals*](http://www.paultaylor.eu/ordinals#intso), in the *Journal of Symbolic Logic* 61 (1996) 705-744, particularly Section 3. This in turn built on *Categorical Set Theory: a characterisation of the Category of Sets* by Gerhard Osius in the *Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra* 4 (1974) 79-119.

We are working in some given elementary topos, whose objects I will call **carriers** in order to avoid the word *set*.

A model of a fragment of set theory is given by a carrier $X$ equipped with a binary relation $\epsilon$ that it is convenient to regard as a map $\epsilon:X\to P X$ to the powerset.  That is, it is a **coalgebra** for the **covariant powerset functor**.

We say that $(X,\epsilon)$ is **extensional** if the map $\epsilon:X\to P X$ is mono (1-1).

The definition of when the coalgebra is **well founded** involves a pullback diagram and is given in the paper.

Then an **ensemble** is an extensional well founded coalgebra.

Applying the covariant powerset functor to one ensemble gives another.

Between any two ensembles there is at most one **coalgebra homomorphism**, and it is mono.  This captures **inclusion** in the set-theoretic sense.

The category of ensembles is therefore a preorder. It is a *large* category in the same sense that familiar categories such as that of groups in a topos are large.

We can rehearse the standard definitions of pairing, functions, etc from set theory using ensembles and show that this preorder provides a model of the Zermelo axioms.

Natural numbers (infinity) and the axiom of choice are inherited from the given topos if it has them.

As to the axiom-scheme of replacement, understanding this from a categorical perspective was one of my principal aims in this work.  The comments in my JSL paper are really quite naive and should be discounted in favour of those at the very end of my book, However, I got interested in other things and never pursued this to a satisfactory conclusion.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for pointing out your paper, but my question was asking for a way to construct a model of ETCS (i.e. with AC) from a well-pointed topos with NNO (i.e. no AC assumed), _without_ passing through Zermelo(-Fraenkel) set theory.

Comment: @David, I have just tried to send you an email in Adelaide but it was bounced with a 554 error.

Comment: Try droberts.[largest known Fermat prime]@gmail.com